# Finding device Tx frequency with Yardstick One

Tags: frequency, sdr

I wanted to get into RF hacking (to decode and reproduce ceiling fan control), and decided to buy a Yardstick one.  After having played with the YS1 for a while I now better understand that it is NOT sdr...but still very handy when it comes time to transmit my signal.  But first, I need to find more info on the Transmitted signal.

I know nothing about the fan transmitter, no FCC ID, and so I first need to find what frequency it transmits on.  Is it possible for the YS1 to help me find the frequency?  Or do I need a real SDR to find the frequency?